# Twilio Chatbot through Website - User has no phone number

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

My client's use case is a `Barista Chatbot`, but only accessible through their website. An icon in the lower right of web pages allowing the user to click and ask questions of an automated chatbot.

I've created a Studio Flow that works from a cell phone using SMS.

Now I need to trigger that Studio Flow for a user that opens the chat popup.

The website is ASP.NET v4.8 with MVC and .NET Framework 4.8.

The problem I'm having is finding any documentation/example code on how to create a Conversation without a user having a phone number. I'm sure this is possible?

```
        // Create a Participant
        var participant = ParticipantResource.Create(
            messagingBindingAddress: "<NONUMBER FOR HERE>",
            messagingBindingProxyAddress: _twilioPhoneNumber,
            pathConversationSid: conversation.Sid
        );
```

We don't have any intention of collecting phone numbers from users at the point of this interaction.

Can someone point me on how to add a webchat participant without a phone number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating a chat participant for a conversation, you only need to provide their [identity](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/identity), not a `messageBingingAddress` or `messageBindingProxyAddress`.

```cs
        var participant = ParticipantResource.Create(
            identity: "<Chat User Identity>",
            pathConversationSid: "CHXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        );
```

See also [the example in the docs here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/api/conversation-participant-resource?code-sample=code-create-conversation-participant-chat&code-language=C%23&code-sdk-version=5.x).